# Installing bigalgebra package for R 3.0

Tags: linux, r, package

I keep getting an error when I try to install the `bigalgebra` package.

`'bigalgebra' is not available (for R version 3.0.1)`

I already have the `bigmemory` package installed (I had the same problem for this one, and I can't remember how I resolved it) . I tried to get the bigalgebra_0.8.1.tar.gz but I can't find it. Also, on R forge it isn't available (https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=556) (failed to built). Did anyone have the same problem.

Should I just install an older R version? Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Same problem here, it also isn't available through either Cran or Bioconductor for R 2.15

Comment: I've contacted the authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's currently not in Cran, Bioconductor, nor successfully building on R-Forge, you will have to build it yourself from source.

The source of the big memory project can be checked out via SVN via the following command I obtained from the [group page on R-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/?group_id=556):

```
svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/bigmemory/
```

This will create a directory called `bigmemory`. The `bigalgebra` package is found in `bigmemory/pkg/bigalgebra`.

Before going any further, you will need both the BLAS and Boost libraries installed on your **OS**, otherwise installation will fail.

From `R` you can then directly install the package from the directory:

```
install.packages("bigmemory/pkg/bigalgebra/", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

I was successfully able to build and install it on `R 3.0.0` on Mac OSX.